# Function doesn't work after change its environment

Tags: r, function, environment

I'd like to call reinforcements to help with this error as follows:

First I created my environment:

```
envizito <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
attr(envizito, "name") <- "envizito"
```

and assigned a new variable called `aaa`:

```
envizito$aaa <- 12
```

I created a function:

```
FUNn <- function() {print(envizito$aaa)}

environment(FUNn)
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

Then, I changed its environment to be in `envizito`:

```
environment(FUNn) <- envizito

environment(FUNn)
# <environment: 0xc20b0a8>
#attr(,"name")
#[1] "envizito"
```

But after call `FUNn()` it showed the error below:

```
FUNn()
# Error in { : could not find function "{"
```

PS: Although `environment(FUNn)` points to the same place in memory it didn't appear when I had called `ls()`

```
ls(envir = envizito, all.names = TRUE)
# [1] "aaa"
```

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated! 
thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{` like everything else in R which is not an object, is a function. When you created `envizito`, you appointed the empty environment as its parent. The empty environment as its name hints, contains no objects i.e. it is empty.

When you changed `FUNn`'s environment to `envisito` you made its parent environment the empty environment. When you call `FUNn` (the function definition is in the global environment) it searches in its environment (i.e. `envisito`) for function `{` (the first function it finds in `FUNn`). It cannot find `{` within `envisito`, so it looks one environment up. That environment, however, is the `empty environment` which is empty. Therefore, it fails with an error that it cannot find function `{`.

Comment: When I rerun this example appointing the `parent.frame()` (i.e. R_GlobalEnv) as its parent, everything works fine. I didn't know this behavior by appointing the empty environment as parent of some function. Thank you for your help!